# JBoss EAP 8 - Release Date

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-eap-7

I don't appear to be able to find any information on the proposed release date for EAP 8. WildFly 11 has been out a few months now.

We have clients running our financial services product on either WildFly or Enterprise Application Platform and would like to be able to plan product and technology upgrades with them.

I'd be very grateful if I could be pointed to a release roadmap or be given a rough idea when EAP 8 may become available.

We would also be open to receiving early beta versions to assist with testing.

Comment: EAP 7.1 is released few weeks back. EAP 8 is not in planning phase, it will take couple of years to release

Comment: Thanks Abhijit.

EAP 7.1 is supported with Java 1.8. Can you tell me which EAP release is planned for support with Java 1.9 please ?

Comment: If you're using EAP then you've got a relationship with RedHat.  Why not ask them?

Comment: @DavidHughes Red Hat is evaluating as Oracle Java's roadmap and version scheme has changed [1]
[1]http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html